# A Slider with Ajax-loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, slider

I have this following page pagination:

```
<div class="pagination-centered hide">
  <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="current"><a href="">1</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="./index.php?path=index2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="./index.php?path=index3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using the infinity plugin to load my content by scrolling, something like this:

```
        $("#teaser-slide-ul").infinitescroll({
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: "<div class='alert-box secondarty' style='margin-top: 10px;'>Sie haben das Ende der Bildergalerie erreicht!</div>",
                msgText: "<div class='alert-box secondarty' style='margin-top: 10px;'>Lade neue Bilder nach...</div>"
            },
            navSelector:  '.pagination',
            nextSelector: '.pagination li.next a',
            itemSelector: '.teaser-slide',
            dataType:     'html'
        });
```

This request add the content from *.teaser-slide* to an *li*. My problem is that I need this exactly ajax-loading for a slider. I don't know which slider can perform something like this and how I could implement it.

Summary: I need a slider which can load a specific content from any page that is linked in the navigation after the *li* with the class *current*.

Comment: Seems very specific what you need...It might be doable with that plugin but why not try and build it?

Comment: @elclanrs The problem is that I don't know much about JavScript :( Infinitescroll does the job perfect but I need something similar for the slider.